# Make a div scroll when i reach a certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to make a div (button) scroll when I reach a certain scrolling point.Also i want to add classes to the other elements on the page.Somehow it isnt working.Here is the code Im using for the scroll,but I dont quite understand it.Please help me

```
$(window).load(function () {

    var nav = get_nav();

    if (!(nav.is_msie && nav.ver <= 6)) {
        var tmp1 = $('#tag_container').css('position');
        var cur_w_offset = start_offset = $('#butoni').offset().top;
        var bp = $('#right_content');
        var pt = $('#butoni');
        cur_w_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (cur_w_offset >= start_offset) {
            bp.addClass('flyingbuy');
        } else {
            pt.css('top', 'auto');
        }
        if (window.content_center != true || window.c != false) {
            window.buydeal_forpresent = false;
        }
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var tmp = $('#tag_container').css('position');
            ur_w_offset = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (cur_w_offset >= start_offset) {
                bp.addClass('flyingbuy');
                $('#tag_container').css('height', 'auto');
                $('#tag_container_bialo').slideDown('slow');
            } else {
                bp.removeClass('flyingbuy');
                $('#tag_container').css(({
                    position: "fixed",
                    height: "101px"
                }));
                $('#tag_container_bialo').slideUp('slow');
            }
            if (!window.buydeal_forpresent) {
                var nvp_panel = $('#right_content');
                var nvp_pricetag = $('#butoni');
                var bialo_height = $('#tag_container_bialo').height() + 20;
                var offset_top = nvp_pricetag.offset().top - nvp_panel.offset().top + 16;
                if (tmp == 'fixed') {
                    $('#gift').css('position', 'fixed');
                    var left = $('#butoni').offset().left + 223 - 18;
                    $('#gift').css('top', 16 + bialo_height + 'px');
                    $('#gift').css('left', left + 'px');
                } else {
                    $('#gift').css('position', 'absolute');
                    $('#gift').css('top', offset_top);
                    $('#gift').css('left', '205px');
                    $('#gift').animate({
                        top: offset_top + bialo_height
                    }, 400);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

I have a problem now.I've been working here : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zte6T/3/)

I don't want the text div to scroll that way.When the pages reaches at the button's level ,I want the txt to show,sliding down and moving along with the button.But,the text needs to be BEFORE the button.I don't know why it grows when sliding down.The sliding up part is ok.

---

Ok,i found out the growing part.I didnt specify the height.
I really dont know how can I make the txt appear before the button and slide together.Like this:

TEXT
BUTTON

Comment: What's the question here? "How is this code working", or "It's not working, how can I fix it" ?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't blindly copy-paste code you don't understand.

Comment: For scrolling events check: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to achieve, and there seems to be a lot of code in your post that doesn't directly relate to your question. Here's a much simpler piece of code that seems to do what you want (if I'm interpreting your goal correctly):

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Zte6T/1/)

```
$(function(){
    var btn = $('.button');
    var btnPosTop = btn.offset().top;
    var win = $(window);
    win.scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop){
            //we've reached the button
            btn.css({position:'fixed',top:0,marginTop:0});
        }else if(btn.css('position') === 'fixed'){
            //if we scroll back up past the button's original position, and the button had previously been changed to its fixed position, we change it back
            btn.css({position:'',top:'',marginTop:'100px'});
        }
    });
});
```

When the page loads, we get the original position, relative to the document, of the button's top edge. We then bind the window's scroll event to code that checks how far down the user has scrolled (`win.scrollTop()`). It compares that value to the button's original position. If it's found to be greater than or equal to the button's original position, that means the button should start scrolling with us by changing its CSS `position` to `fixed`. The `else if` part returns the button to its original position when the user scrolls back up.

Comment: Omg thanks a lot.You really understood what I wanted to do.Now the button slides with the page when we reach it.
I also want to add a div (some text) that appears at the moment when the button is fixed.
SO ,when the button moves this text moves along with it.

I think it has smth to do with adding a class,but i'm not sure how.

If you cud help me with this it would be great

Anyway,thanks for the help :)

Comment: You clearly need to spend some time studying Javascript & jQuery, and maybe HTML/CSS as well. I say that because you should be able to figure out the solution to this text issue based off what I put above. Anyway, you should put the code for making the text appear inside of the if(scrollTop >= btnPosTop) statement. Just like the button, it should get a position of fixed (either by setting it in JS, or by adding a class to the containing div that has its css specified as having position:fixed) so that it moves along as the page scrolls.

Comment: Ok thanks
You're right about the studying ,but I am a begginer.That's why it's a bit difficult for me now.Thanks,I'll try out what you wrote me above

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(top>879)
    {   $("div").addClass('yourclass');
    }
});
```

Here `879` is assigned scrolling point