# Slide div with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make a div scroll when i reach a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471382/make-a-div-scroll-when-i-reach-a-certain-point)

I have a problem now.I've been working here : http://jsfiddle.net/Zte6T/3/

I don't want the text div to scroll that way.When the pages reaches at the button's level ,I want the txt to show,sliding down and moving along with the button.But,the text needs to be BEFORE the button.The sliding up part is ok.

Comment: **Note to all:** Please, fiddles are external resources that should _complement_ a quality question and/or a quality answer. Neither should be just links on their own. Think of our children!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want, but here's a version that might start to get you there:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/gw8Hr/

Rather than making both the `.button` and the `.pricetag` have a fixed position, put the `.button` inside the `.pricetag_container`, and make the `pricetag_container` have the fixed positioning.

Also, I see that this is building off an answer I provided to a previous post of yours. I've modified the fiddle I created for that response to to what I think you want. This might be better than the fiddle I posted above:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebiewener/Zte6T/4/