# jScroll is buggy?

Tags: jquery

I have implemented **jScroll** plugin from [here](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/jScroll/)

If you go to view [my project](http://projekt6.netboss.dk/) you will notice that the shopping cart and category section is not entirely shown (or even not shown at all if you scroll down with a high speed)...

Do you see any reason? I am doing something wrong in my design? Because the original plugin seems to work nice even for high speed scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some code, it's hard to know what's going wrong. However, here's a solution I posted a while back for something similar that works without the jScroll plugin: [Make a div scroll when i reach a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471382/make-a-div-scroll-when-i-reach-a-certain-point/7472409#7472409)

I think its functionality is a lot better because you don't get stuck with this animated "bobbing" of the shopping cart slowly catching up with you. It just stays put as you scroll.

Comment: I've implemented your solution but it has a bug in IE9, can you please have a look? http://projekt6.netboss.dk/

Comment: If you open up IE9's dev tools you'll see that the location of the `.scroll` element is actually correct -- you just can't see it. Not sure what is causing this bug, but adding 'z-index:0' seems to fix it. You might need to actually add this via JS in the callback to the scroll event (in my fiddle, that would be inside of `wind.scroll(function(){...})`, and in fact modify it each time in that callback (alternate between z-index:0 and z-index:1)

Comment: Thanks... As you can notice here `view-source:http://projekt6.netboss.dk/` I've added this `z-index` trick but still does not work...